# How can I do feature mapping (pop) from JSON format to tabular format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
    id      var_map
0   7068    {'feature_1': 2.0, 'feature_2': 4.0, 'feature_3': 8.0, 'feature_4': 8.0}
1   7116    {'feature_1': '2', 'feature_2': 5.0, 'feature_3': 7.0}
2   7154    {'feature_1': 1.0, 'feature_2': 8.0, 'feature_3': 17.0}
```

Here's what I want

```
    id      feature_1  feature_2  feature_3   feature_4   feature_5
0   7068    2.0        4.0        8.0         8.0               
1   7116    2          5.0                    7.0         
2   7154    1.0                               8.0         17.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) with `DataFrame` contructor and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('var_map').values.tolist(), index=df.index))

print (df)
     id feature_1  feature_2  feature_3  feature_4
0  7068         2        4.0        8.0        8.0
1  7116         2        5.0        7.0        NaN
2  7154         1        8.0       17.0        NaN
```

But if input is `json` better should be use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

Comment: @Haleemur Ali - Thank you.

Comment: This works really well, I should read more about `json_normalize`